# Trying to create smooth "swoop" shape using CSS3

Tags: css, shapes

I'm trying to create a smooth "swoop" shape with CSS/no images. I've used Chris Coyier's "[Tabs with round out borders](http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/)" technique and I'm pretty close, but the rounding isn't quite as smooth as I'd like. I've tweaked and tweaked and I'm just not getting it.

There are two issues I'm seeing. The first is, it's just not a perfectly smooth swoop. It jags just a bit.  And the second is, of course, in IE (8/9/10) - there's a very fine line showing in the dark blue below the main site navigation (Home / Volunteer etc). I don't know if that's related to the swoop stuff at all so apologies if that's off-topic, but it's driving me crazy since I can't figure out what's causing it.

Here's the site: http://texascasa.wpengine.com/

And here's a [Pastebin of the relevant code](http://pastebin.com/nwdxKUw0). I'm using SASS - let me know if you'd rather I scrape the plain CSS for debugging and I'll be happy to put that up.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use CSS shapes for this effect?

Comment: A quick look indicates that you might be having trouble with the fine line between the shape and the div because you're using ems for positioning that don't resolve to integer values. I would consider experimenting with either absolute pixels or ems / rems that resolve to whole numbers.

Comment: Mostly I'm using them because it seems like it should be possible, and I try to use CSS instead of images when I can. :) Good tip on the ems/absolute pixels, I'll look into that thanks!

Comment: Fair enough. In my experience, however, CSS shapes tend to be brittle from a maintainability perspective - they can't achieve certain effects (so have to be reimplemented as the design changes) and it can be tricky to work out how they're put together / debug them. Just my opinion.

Comment: True words - I'm definitely finding them "fun" to debug. :) This is my first time using them for anything complex, we'll see if that happens again.

Comment: CSS is not the right technology for drawing shapes. Just because it's *possible* doesn't mean it's right. The correct option for you is probably SVG (yes, IE8 will be a problem with that, but then, it doesn't do `border-radius` either, so you lose nothing, and there are fall-back solutions).